# javascript versioning without ability to change js url. Would etag work?

Tags: versioning, bookmarklet, etag

As part of a bookmarklet, I want to load in a script `www.example.com/a.js`
This file may change in the future so I want to do some versioning on it. 
However, since I must hardcode the url in the bookmarklet, I can't use proper url-versioning .

What would be a good practice to do versioning instead? 
I imagine using *etag* would probably work. I.e.: update the eTag on each version update and have the client request the file with the `If-None-Match` header.

Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> have the client request the file with the If-None-Match header.

That I know of, there is no way to control or set the headers that a browser will use when loading a page resource such as images and script.

ETag is something that should work "out of the box". If the client sends an `ETag` header with the file then the browser should automatically send the `If-None-Match` header for the next request.

One frequently seen method to ensure a fresh file, although less efficient, is to add a time stamp or random number to the script like http://example.com/script.js?1234567. Of course that will force the client to download the script every time. You could instead use different date strings to force a download only once per day or week or month, etc.

And then there is just the good old standard caching headers `expires` and `cache-control` that you can use as well to force a fresh download every X period of time.